# Sometimes, Can't connect to pods on one of the nodes from master in kubernetes

Tags: networking, dns, kubernetes

I have my kubernetes cluster up and running on 3 machines with ubuntu (master and two nodes).I am using Calico for pod network add-on.

I am trying to deploy flask microservice with two pods and load balancer. I have problem with one of the pod which is located on second node. Sometimes the service cannot connect to this pod. Furthermore, I am not able to ping the IP of the pod from master but I can from the other node.
The most strange thing is that after I run  "nslookup hostnames.default.svc.cluster.local DNS_SERVER_IP" on second node everything works correctly.